# include bower component in Ember Controller

Tags: ember.js, bower

I am trying to use js-beautify in my ember application. The module is imported in `app.import('bower_components/js-beautify/js/lib/beautify.js');` in `ember-cli-build.js` but i dont know how to use the `beautify.js`. how can i import the package in my controller? I tried something like this: `import Ember from 'ember';` but with my `bower_components/js-beautify/js/lib/beautify.js` route but it refused to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In all the external modules I worked with in Ember, once they're added to the `ember-cli-build.js` you have the objects they export in the global namespace.

For example, I use [js-cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-cookie) in my project like this after adding an appropiate `app.import` in `ember-cli-build.js`:

```
/* globals Cookie */ // This comment makes jshint happy
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Service.extend({
    saveCookie (name, value) {
        // The Cookie object is available in the global namespace
        Cookie.set(name, value);
    }
});
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 3):

You did correct. but to access js_beautify() use

```
window.js_beautify()
```